# Sharepoint 2010 - Save & Close and discard checkouts

Tags: 2010

I was working in Sharepoint 2010 and have made a load of changes to a page.  Thoughout the day I was frequently saving and closing the page, but not checking in or publishing the page (it needed to be approved before going live).

At the end of the day, I've had two issues, my IE crashed and I subsequently think I may have done a 'discard check out'.  As I haven't checked in or published throughout the day I have I lost all the work I have done?

Does 'save and close' store a local/cached version of edits somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a cache and you won't get your work back, unless you have versioning enabled with major AND minor versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done discard check-out and if you have not enabled the minor version all changes are lost.

The best way to avoid this type of issues is to enable the minor version so that all changes can be preserved and can be reverted in any disaster scenario.